# Syntax error when unpacking in NumPy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

Why does the code below raise a `SyntaxError` on line 5 for Python 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10 (it seems fine for Python 3.11 and 3.12)?

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(5)
new_dim = 3
a = a[:, *[np.newaxis] * new_dim]
```

Was it a bug in former versions of Python?

Comment: Are all your installs of numpy the latest version for each venv (or whatever environment) you run those versions of Python from?

Comment: @Todd yes, they are. All the newest versions of NumPy available on PyPI.

Comment: Yeah, I just verified. It works with 3.12 python but not 3.10. And my numpy package has been updated recently for both.

Comment: This isn't a bug in former versions of Python. In Python 3.11, a [language grammar change introduced in PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#change-1-star-expressions-in-indexes) started allowing star expressions in indexes (your `a[..., *[np.newaxis], ...]`).

Comment: So you're trying to use a new feature in an old version that didn't support it.

Comment: Ok, thanks; I did not know it was a new feature.

Comment: the numpy version is irrelevant for a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Although star expressions in indexes have been introduced in Python 3.11, I just realized it is possible to do it in the following way.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(5)
new_dim = 3
a = a[(...,) + (np.newaxis,) * new_dim]
```